# How to handle questions with seemingly malicious (albeit legal) intent

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, ethics

I came across this question yesterday from a brand new user:

> I recently got pop-up from these websites, pop were screen blocker
>   with infinite repeats: onlinecompleteproducts.in online-helps.com.
>   This is their real ad page: s27.postimg.org/h8ed4trzn/ex1.png But if I
>   open it, it will redirect me to some regional cooking pages of famous
>   sites like about.com. URL doesn't changes & I know how to do that.
>
> How did they HIDE the original content? I tried it opening on several
>   location based proxy servers like USA, CANADA, UK & also state
>   specifics. But it doesn't opens up. Even on my IP where I saw it
>   first.
>
> How can I create infinite POP-UPs like these to lock user on the page?
>
> All help will be appreciated!
>
> Cheers...

I flagged the question, saying that that it needed moderator attention.  My flag was declined with the response:

> "Asking about how someone did something seems like a legitimate
>   question."

This is a fair point, and if this sort of question were posed in an academic or "white hat" sort of context, it would certainly be valid and valuable to the community; however, without that context, and particularly given that this is a new user with no other activity on the site, it seems reasonable to assume that this user is asking for guidance in creating spam.

What is the appropriate action to take in cases like this?  Is the only thing to do in this situation to downvote the question and move on, or is there a more relevant flag that I should have used.  I'm still fairly new to the community, so I'm still figuring out the nuances of what is and isn't appropriate.

Comment: A couple of well known other examples might be the most heavily downvoted question on stack overflow [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3905734/73226) and one, allegedly, posted from the SilkRoad founder [How can I connect to a Tor hidden service using curl in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445285/how-can-i-connect-to-a-tor-hidden-service-using-curl-in-php)

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent

Comment: I've [left a sarcastic remark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26387355/648265) in a (correct) answer and got a few upvotes and no tick.

Comment: In most cases it's not appropriate to pass judgement based upon the intent or inferred intent of the asker.  If you have reservations about what the OP wants to do then just ignore it and move on.  Or vote it down/vote to close if there's not a clear and valid technical question being asked.  But the question itself should live or die based upon its objectively-assessed technical merits, _not_ how legal/illegal or repugnant/agreeable the OP's motives may be.

Comment: I must agree with above. I don't think it's stackoverflow's responsibility to be judges in law. Mostly because it's solely subjective and globally laws are very different. I think answering the questions rather than giving a moral lecture is the way to go.

Comment: How would Ubisoft react if people starting asking directly how to break the security of their products and what actions should stackoverflow be held responsible for? I can't answer this, sorry.

Comment: The person who gave [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13960/8558) seems to have found an interesting way to deal with the [couching-a-question-to-disguise-potentially-malicious-intent problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent/3531#3531). At first I was taken aback by the brazenness of the answerer, but now I think he was doing it to shine a light on the asker.

Comment: I completely agree that it should not be SO's responsibility to make legal or moral judgements; however, we already do, as a community, make judgements about what questions are and are not valuable to the community at large.  On that basis, I don't think it would be too much of a leap for SO, in the future, to collectively decide that questions obviously and specifically intended to elicit help in creating spam or malware are not valuable, and in fact, harmful to the community.  Does anyone else see this as a reasonable possibility for the future, or does that just sound too Orwellian?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In general you would only flag Other if there is an issue with a post that can't be handled by the community it self.

In its current revision the question is too broad/unclear and maybe lacks enough research. For those reasons the following actions seem appropiate now:

- Downvotes: what 9 users did
- Close votes: what 5 users did (as too broad which is indeed a good reason for this question)
- Delete votes: That needs 3 20Krep users (10Krep user after two days) and a score of -3 on the post

As stated by Servy if the reader feels the question is unsavory is **NOT** a reason to down/close vote.

In this case you might even consider to Flag as Spam but it didn't really try to sell us anything and it doesn't have live links in the post so I would leave it at closing.

If you think a quick response from the community is needed drop in a Chatroom, for example <s>[The SO Tavern](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks)</s>(frozen), [the SO Close Voters room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) or the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) to get some quick down and/or close votes, or ask for guidance on how to handle the post.

Remember that it is hard to judge if a question is really looking for an answer to be used in illegal activities. If I ask a question about encryption that can't be broken by the NSA I might very well use that to cover my evil plans or to protect my privacy as a european citizen.

Comment: The NSA example is particularly poignant.