# Potential legal liability when answering a hacker's or terrorist's question?

Tags: discussion, legal

When we answer questions on Stack Overflow, most of us most of the time don't know the asker - who they are, what the purpose of their software is, etc.

What if we were to inadvertently help out a "black hat" hacker, such as one who is out to steal identities or cause other such mayhem?

Even worse, what if it were a terrorist we were inadvertently helping?

If that came to light, we would doubtless feel rotten about it, to say the least; but would there also be possible legal repurcussions/ramifications, even though we *unknowingly* aided such ones?

Is this a concern to anyone else? Has it been discussed?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199353/did-the-stack-exchange-staff-members-assist-in-the-apprehension-of-ross-ulbricht

Comment: I would caution against taking legal advice from programmers, but I am not a lawyer.

Comment: I do my best to shield myself.  If the question mentions 'exploit', 'virus', 'trojan', 'buffer overflow' etc, I down and close vote immediate with a comment explaining why.  Of course, they always claim to be 'investigating', 'learning', 'ethical' etc, as if I always believe what I read on teh internet, lol.

Comment: What if you gave someone directions to the airport and they turned out to be a terrorist? Oh, the guilt!

Comment: I feel bad whenever someone says they're trying to use Python and I don't do anything about it.

Comment: Search engine and even internet are also used by terrorist Or hacker. That doesn't mean to stop both. So, don't worry about. If any one have feel like that then don't use.

Comment: How to counter a black hat? With a tin foil hat! Winter bash is _real_.

Comment: @ChrisGerken Or worse, PHP. _shudders_

Comment: Don't worry;  as of January 1, they don't have to include attribution to your code anymore.  If they don't, authorities might not be able to trace it back to you. :)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I assume you mean the January 1st coming up in a couple of weeks; I hadn't heard anything about such a change. I guess there's a joke here somewhere something like "When code is unattributed, only black hat hackers will..."

Comment: @B.ClayShannon There's a big post on meta.SE at the moment, [The MIT License – Clarity on Using Code on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080/225437);  as of January first (oh, they pushed back to February 1st!), code contributions to Stack Overflow won't be CC-BY-SA, but will be MIT license, with a modification to allow third parties to copy code without attribution.  My joke was just that "if a terrorist uses your code, it would have been traceable to you, since they'd have to provide attribution, but after the change, they won't have to."

Comment: Related: [How can we discuss malicious code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287327/1048572), [How to handle questions with seemingly malicious (albeit legal) intent](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276845/1048572), [How do we handle questions that are potentially or blatantly illegal or malicious?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267699/1048572) and more linked from there

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Yeah, I got it; but then again, some of those cats aren't too bright (like the cat who took a selfie in front of his bunker whose location was subsequently identified and bombed) and maybe they have politely provided attribution. That would be funny (in a non-humourousway).

Answer (score 67):

Our questions and answers use an open license. *Anyone* gets to have access to that knowledge, including people with ill intent.

However, the vast and overwhelming majority of people out there are just trying to get their job done. Or their homework finished on time. Or are trying to learn. I really wouldn't worry about this.

And yes, this has already happened. The [Silk Road operator](http://www.businessinsider.com/silk-road-stack-overflow-post-2013-10?IR=T) [asked questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445285/how-can-i-connect-to-a-tor-hidden-service-using-curl-in-php). No, the people that answered did not get into any hot water. No one knew at the time that the question asker was going to be arrested for running a dark-web drug trafficking site.

Comment: That makes sense to me; but the way some governments operate still concerns me in this regard. I can see them saying, "Ignorance is no excuse - you helped them, and thus - off with your head!" (probably not literally).

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: If you live in a country where law enforcement can make that stick, don't use the internet. Get out now. Stack Overflow is the least of your worries.

Comment: Wow @MartijnPieters - I never knew that even happened, that was an interesting read.

Comment: In a related, depressing case: Iran imprisoned and nearly executed the author of a photo gallery application because it was used by some porn sites. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saeed_Malekpour

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: Although "Ignorance is no excuse" is a real legal doctrine, it's shorthand for "Ignorance *of the law* is no excuse" (Latin *Ignorantia **juris** non excusat*). IANAL, but I know that ignorance of facts and circumstances absolutely *can* be an excuse, either mitigating a crime or completely negating it, provided that your actions were reasonable and otherwise legal. Some relevant legal doctrines, that you might want to Google, include *mens rea*, *criminal negligence*, *recklessness*, and *due diligence*.

Comment: _"
And while this won’t appear anywhere in the criminal charges against Ulbricht, the court of computer-programmer opinion may duly note that he asked two questions on the site, but didn’t take the trouble to answer anyone else’s"_ - What a jerk.

Comment: @peeskillet To be fair to the drug trafficker, he could have used another account for non-felonious purposes and answered questions with that one. :)

Comment: Don't forget that you need [mens rea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_rea) (a guilty mind) to be convicted of a crime. If you've just walked out your house and someone asks you where a certain house number is, you say, "that's it there", and they go and kill someone inside the house, you are not guilty of anything as it wasn't your [intent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intention) to cause anyone harm.