# How to handle legitimate questions about an illegal project

Tags: discussion, legal

Recently, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73393002/variation-swatches-for-woocommerce-image-carousel-bug/73394547). The question is about creating an image carousel in WooCommerce; so the question itself isn't too bad. However, the author provides *a link to* example screenshots and notes that they may be NSFW because they depict sex toys.

Stack Overflow doesn't allow questions asking for illegal content, but I couldn't find any guidance on legitimate questions asking for help on a (potentially) illegal project. In [some countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_toy#Legal_issues), selling sex toys is illegal; so answering this question could be a possible legal risk for some users (I'm not a lawyer, but I'd guess the authorities wouldn't be too happy). This question also reminded me of [Ross Ulbricht's famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445285/how-can-i-connect-to-a-tor-hidden-service-using-curl-in-php); however, that question didn't state what the code was going to be used for.

So, how are/should these questions be handled? The questions themselves are on-topic and may be useful to others who want to use the answers for legal purposes, but there is still an illegal aspect to the question (at least in some countries).

Comment: If you got a problem with the content, or are legally barred from answering questions in relation to the content, then don't answer it. I only see 4 countries where this is listed as being illegal, that still leaves several hundred countries of people who are free to answer such questions.

Comment: Related: [Potential legal liability when answering a hacker's or terrorist's question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312584/2821954)

Comment: I don't think that it's OK to include links to NSFW content, by the other hand, if a links it's not helful to understand and/or be able to answer the question, IMHO, it should be removed.

Comment: Seems kind of silly. There's no possibly way for Stack to even be aware of, let alone enforce, the various restrictions on online content of dozens of countries.

Comment: How about we just don't acknowledge lunacy?

Answer (score 14):

Stack Overflow is a US company and "illegal" is generally defined by US laws. The fact that some particular thing is potentially illegal in one or several other countries does not make it "illegal" to be posted on SO (being it encryption, use of VPN, images of sex toys/war crimes/rainbow flags..., political statements potentially blocking whole countries from using SO - [Are political profiles that could possibly affect the participations of other users allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298950/are-political-profiles-that-could-possibly-affect-the-participations-of-other-us)).

One other hand, "not-illegal" is not really a good reason to include such content in questions/answers. It is reasonably to have it in one's profile, but for posts it would be a distraction at best and ["fluff"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-like-greetings-signatures-thanks-etc-when-editin) in most cases.

About the specific question linked:

- the question does not include information needed to answer in the post - so you can safely vote to close as "missing debugging info"
- there is absolutely no need to use controversial (and potentially copyrighted) images in that question - while some narrow subset of questions (i.e., image processing) may need a specific image, questions about HTML layout/CSS do not require specific images. The fact the OP did not want to spend time on creating an alternative set of images to talk to the company's support potentially shows lack of effort spent to craft the question
- the question is very likely duplicate
- the question may be considered SPAM as there is not much information in the question and link to a site with shop-like domain. (That's probably a stretch; I'd stay with downvote/[VTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420).)

What you could do if you find questions with visible NSFW/otherwise questionable content that is not SPAM (this is not the case for the linked question as the OP started with an NSFW warning and linking the content instead of inlining it):

- if content there is unrelated to the question (historical/personal notes, signature, etc.), edit the post to remove it
- if the question includes not-exactly-appropriate images, edit to make images to be links instead of inline and add an NSFW warning if appropriate.
- consider if downvote/VTC is appropriate—getting a post to -3 makes it eligible for deletion by community members in case of outrageous content.
- consider if flagging for moderator attention is appropriate. I.e., if the OP reverted similar edits in the past or you think some specific action from moderators is needed (immediate deletion of the post, some communication to the user, reviewing of account actions,...). Be very specific if you decide to use a custom moderator flag.
- use your own judgement whether to answer such a question - there isn't any requirement to provide an answer to any particular question.