# How to counter people jumping to conclusions and closing questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Not my question:

[Loading custom DLLs instead of original DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042757/loading-custom-dlls-instead-of-original-dlls)

and not the first time.  This will likely get closed. It is a legitimate question, IMO. Yet the discussion in the comments has invariably gone to "THIS IS MALWARE YOU ARE DOING UNCOMMON THINGS BAD BAD CLOSE QUESTION" Frankly, the responders don't have any idea of the reasons the OP wants to know this. Nor, frankly, should they.

How do we get people to stick to the question at hand vs. attempting to infer the usage (and in that process, jumping to conclusions about their intentions...)?

Comment: If the comments are noise, flag them as "Too chatty".

Comment: But it becomes a problem when that leads to a mob mentality over closing the Q because of that judgment.

Comment: There's not much you can do to stop a mob from gang-closing a question.  But, if the comments are influencing judgement and they don't add anything to the overall clarification of the question, perhaps the comments are too noisy.

Comment: The question got closed for being unclear, and I have to agree with that. The op doesn't ever ask a question

Comment: [How to handle questions with seemingly malicious albeit legal intent?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276845)

Comment: I know the answer to that question.  No way I'm going to post it, it fails the basic "would my mom be ahead with this?" test.   "The responders don't have any idea of the reasons" because the OP did not tell them.  Surely there is a better way to do whatever he wants to do but he does not give anybody a chance to propose it.  The blame here is **entirely** on the OP, there is no reason whatsoever for anybody to put up with crap questions like this.

Comment: *"Nor, frankly, should they"* - I disagree., Frank Understanding the context is how we avoid [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem case is asking a very unclear question. There is no clear, concise problem statement anywhere in it. Instead, the users coming across this question have to piece information from both before and after the screenshot to arrive at the actual question. So that is why it initially got closed as "unclear what you're asking".

I've made some edits to the question, including clarifying the problem statement, this will hopefully get the question back on track and keep it from being re-closed.

For future reference: "Any help is appreciated" and similar formulations are, while usually intended to be nice, superfluous and not really needed on this site. Usually people will edit these out on sight as they count as noise.

> How do we get people to stick to the question at hand vs. attempting
>   to infer the usage (and in that process, jumping to conclusions about
>   their intentions...)?

In theory, that shouldn't really matter. In practice however, we're all human beings here, and as programmers we have an acute disdain for malware and spam. So anything that appears to be intended for that matter is likely to attract downvotes. Nothing much we (or you) can do about that.

Comment: Note: the OP of the Meta question is not the OP of the question under discussion.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I noticed, thats why I removed some of the language suggesting it.

Comment: "Any help appreciated" and such fluff aren't nice at all, they are just extra work. They might be meant to be self-deprecating, ingratiating, or to keep to the proper forms, but simply show either willful disregard or at least obliviousness of the local community.