# How do we deal with legitimate questions that are terrible ideas?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at [Any way to detect the "Stay" button once it been clicked - window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640824/any-way-to-detect-the-stay-button-once-it-been-clicked-window-onbeforeunload) and the thought of a webpage opening up other pages because you hit 'stay' on that dialogue makes me sick.

I would attempt to close vote it, but I have no idea which flag to give it - or if it is even deserving of one. Do we encourage people asking questions about implementing ideas like this?

Comment: possibly related - [How to handle questions with seemingly malicious (albeit legal) intent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276845/1028804), the example there was asking how to create infinite popups

Comment: Yes - that's a perfect example of the types of questions I mean.

Comment: It reminds me about this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214011/is-it-possible-to-display-https-in-the-url-without-using-https  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's to close?  The question is concise, on-topic, has a clear objective and is clearly posed.

I'm not going to disagree that there's *plenty* to dislike about it, but disliking a question doesn't make it off-topic.

There is likely a very clear answer; people have tried a lot of phishing-related attacks based on the UI of a specific browser, and if we weren't able to detect or at least keep up with those sorts of attacks, we wouldn't be able to have more secure systems.  (Although in honesty, the security for web browsers is falling apart.)

I see no reason for the question to be closed.  Hopefully someone can answer it definitively, too.  (Then, y'know, open a bug report with Mozilla or Google to fix it if it *is* possible.)

Comment: *sigh* you're right. I just hope I don't have the misfortune to visit any site they has done this on...